# Como formatar exibição de resultados

Tags: php

Preciso mostrar dados da tabela como date, só não sei como fazer a conversão.

Ele retorna o resultado como está no banco: `00000000` e preciso retornar para `00/00/0000`

**Tenho o seguinte código:**

```
<?php while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)): ?>
    <table>
         <tr>
             <th>Data:</th>                         
             <td><?php echo $linha['DATA'] ?></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Meu `$select` só tem o `SELECT * FROM`.

Comment: No banco está `00000000` mesmo ou está `0000-00-00`?

Comment: por que no banco você não salva data ao invés de string? e mesmo que seja string, por que remover a formatação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para formatar datas em PHP, pode usar a função `date`:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($linha['DATA']));
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui. Muito Obrigado, já vou estar aceitando a resposta.

Comment: Teria como formatar um CPF também?

Comment: Como está retornando o seu CPF? @PedroHenrique marque como solucionada por favor.

Comment: 00000000000 também

Comment: O php não tem nenhuma função pronta para nosso cpf, então utilizamos esse valor que ele espera uma variavel passada

Comment: Ok obrigado mesmo cara!!

Answer (score 2):

A solução seria a seguinte:

```
<?php $novadata = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($linha['DATA'])); ?>
<td><?php echo $novadata ?></td>
```

strtotime para converter para time com / ou -, guardar numa variável php e imprimi-la de seguida.